# Why does browser open twice after Python's time.sleep(1)?

Tags: python, subprocess, tornado, sleep, pid

I am creating a Python web application with the Tornado Framework. I wanted to make the testing process faster, so I use the `subprocess` module to end the process using the same port. When I did not have the `time.sleep(1)` call, I was unable to use the port because it did not close before I tried to listen to it again.

The code works when using sleep, however `webbrowser.open_new(...)` gets called twice. The first time it is unable to use the port, but the second tab it opens with a listening port.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()

    for line in out.splitlines():
        if 'python' in line:
            pid = int(line.split(None, 1)[0])
            if pid != os.getpid():
                os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
                time.sleep(1)

    webbrowser.open_new('http://localhost:' + str(PORT) + '/')

    application.listen(PORT)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Why does the browser open twice?

Output:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8CXO.jpg

Comment: Could you please post an un-edited (or less incorrectly edited) version of your code, and / or the output of your program?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're describing. When I add the minimal amount of code required to duplicate your set up, then run `python torn.py &`, let the server start up, then run `python torn.py &` again, I see the original server get killed by a `KeyboardInterrupt`, the new one starts, and my web browser opens one tab that opens correctly. Are you using `tornado.autoreload` or creating the `application` with `debug=True`? That might explain this behavior, since any change to the source file will reload the script.

Comment: Output of program: http://i.imgur.com/jjeXjDy.gif. As you can see the browser opens once before it can connect to the port, and once again after it is connected.

Comment: Also, blindly killing any python process that isn't the current process seems like... well, a really bad idea.